# When is a square matrix uniquely determined when the row sums and the column sums are given?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Define a $A-matrix$ as a matrix consisted of only the elements of set $A$. 
Let $ r_1,...,r_n $be the row sums and $c_1,...,c_n $be the column sums. For what $2n$-tuple $(r_1,...,r_n,c_1,...,c_n)$ is there a unique $A-matrix$ consisted of only  satisfying those sums?

Comment: This rather depends on what exactly the set $A$ is.

Comment: "Contingency table counts" may be as a helpful search term if $A$ is a set of natural numbers. Existence of a solution with arbitrary nonnegative integer entries is certain provided $\sum r_i = \sum c_i$ holds (both giving the totals of all matrix entries by summing either set of *marginal totals*).  Uniqueness is comparatively rare, though it might be contrived for special choices of set $A$.

Comment: A good introduction to the case where $A = \mathbb N$ is given [here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~barvinok/typical.pdf) (Barvinok, 2009).

Comment: If $A$ is closed under subtraction, then there are no unique cases, since you can always add $P$ and subtract $Q$ for any two different permutation matrices $P,Q$ without affecting the row and column sums.